# reversing rows for indexes, python

Tags: python, algorithm, indexing, reverse

I have data with (x,y) coordinates that origins in the lefttop corner. I turn into a matrix with indexes starting from 0 that looks like that:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4|
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9|
|10 |11 |12 |13 |14|
|15 |16 |17 |18 |19|
|20 |21 |22 |23 |24|
```

for example (x,y)=(1,4) id = y*5 + x = 21. But i want it to origin in the left bottom so that i obtain a matrix with indexing like that:

```
| 20| 21| 22| 23| 24|
| 15| 16| 17| 18| 19|
| 10| 11| 12| 13| 14|
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |  9|
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  4|
```

so basically reversing the rows. Is there a way to do that in pythonic way? What would be the most computationally efficient way to achieve it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about whether "Pythonic" or not, but the most direct and efficient way to me is simply just:

`u = [v[5 * (len(v) // 5 - i // 5 - 1) + i % 5] for i in xrange(len(v))]`

**EDIT:**

If you feel uncomfortable about these divisions and modulos, an alternative without any math calculation(but might be less efficient) is:

`sum([v[i: i+5] for i in xrange(0, len(v), 5)][::-1], [])`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how *pythonic* this is, but it works fine

```
for i in len(v)//2:
      v[i], v[-i] = v[-i], v[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the array by `x`

```
>>> M = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]
>>> M[::-1]
[[9, 10, 11], [6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either `list(reversed(x))` or `x[::-1]` like:

```
matrix=[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19]]
backwards=matrix[::-1]
inverted=list(reversed(matrix))
```

`reversed` returns a backwards iterator that `list` converts to a list, and `[::-1]` returns a list splice taking the elements backwards.

Answer (score 0):

When the shape of your matrix is `width, height = 5,  5`, the general formula to get the bottom up index from the list index is:

```
width*(height-index//height-1)+index%height
```